# Magento 1.9 join table issue

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection, sql, join-table

I'm having an issue with Magento 1.9.2.4 trying to  make a join on my collection, here's the problem:

Actually I've got a custom table named product_banner which I'm getting by:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('mymodule_productbanner/productbanner')->getCollection();
```

But I need to join this table with `catalog_category_entity_varchar`, I've tried solution:

```
    $catalogTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/category');

    $collection = Mage::getModel('exablack_productbanner/productbanner')->getCollection()->getSelect()->join(array('category' => $catalogTable),
        'main_table.category_id = category.entity_id AND category.attribute_id = 41');
```

But for no avail...
The pure sql query I need to run to get my desired result would be:

```
    select catalog_category_entity_varchar.value, product_banner.banner_url, 
    product_banner.text from product_banner inner join catalog_category_entity_varchar 
    on product_banner.category_id = catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id and 
    catalog_category_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 41;
```

How can I achieve this with magento collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with below code as I **haven't run a query on MySQL** because I have no any custom module table include with category id field but I build it based on your collection

```
$collection =
Mage::getModel('mymodule_productbanner/productbanner')->getCollection()
->addFieldToSelect('banner_url');

$attribute =
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttribute('catalog_category',
'name');

$collection->getSelect()
     ->join(array('category_varchar' => $attribute->getBackendTable()),'category_varchar.entity_id=
 main_table.category_id',array('value'))
     ->where('category_varchar.attribute_id = ?',$attribute->getId());

echo $collection->getSelect();
die;
```

and run this query on MySQL.Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Your solved my problem, thanks a lot +1

Comment: @PedrodeAlbuquerque accept him to answer if really help you. so it will help others.